# Why are the images not loading on GitHub?

Tags: html, css, image, github, markdown

As you can see in the screenshot below, the images in the README.md file are not loading on GitHub.

Screenshot of GitHub repo:

[image]

Here's the html section in the README file. Yes I could just use markdown to include the images, but it was looking a bit weird. The images are located in the images folder, so I'm using relative link to access the image, but it doesn't seem it load on GitHub.

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:left; align-items:center; text-align:center;">
   <div style="text-align:center; margin-right:20px;">
      <img src="images/Rohan_Nag_image.jpeg" alt="Rohan Nag" width="100" height="100">
      <br>
      <a href="https://github.com/nagrohan579">Rohan Nag</a>
   </div>
   <div style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="images/Ronita_Adhikari_image.jpg" alt="Ronita Adhikari" width="100" height="100">
      <br>
      <a href="https://github.com/ronitaadhikari">Ronita Adhikari</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out, what do I do here?
Here is the GitHub repo link if you want to check it out:
[GitHub repo link](https://github.com/nagrohan579/bank_management_system_complete)